# MVC 5 select list issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have got a number of problems:

1. Why will

   ```
   <select id="SetLang" data-bind="options: languageSettingEx, 
   optionsText: 'Settedlanguage', optionsValue: 'slid' "> 
   </select>
   ```

   but

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguageSettingEx,
       (SelectList)Model.languageSettingItemsEx, new
       {
           id = "slid",
           data_bind = " options: languageSettingEx, optionsText: 'Settedlanguage', optionsValue: 'slid'"
       })
   ```

   this model is

   ```
   public class langViewModel
   {
   public string SelectedLanguageSettingEx { get; set; }
   public SelectList languageSettingItemsEx { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   in then using knockout to read the values and bind to the list, which works its in the normal select, I have also got the same type of way all over my application however this on fails.

   Gives me the error

   > There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedLanguageSettingEx'.

   this is knoutout.js bound from a JSON object
2. I want to either bind this to a call back on a controller, or set a Session variable

Comment: Can we see the data types of the Model? What is `languageSettingItemsEx`?

Comment: if i go to another area where I have a '@Html.DropDownListFor' and bind 'languageSettingEx' instead it works fine and there is no difference between the two :S

Comment: I figured out why its because on the other I was setting a default value and this on I am not

Comment: I know tis not in the quesion but i was missing this off my controller  'model.languageSettingItemsEx = new SelectList(languageSettingDDL);'